# Converting linear acceleration into moment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, solid-state-physics, acceleration, torque, moment

I am stuck on a simple physics problem. I have made a shaking test on an object, i have measured the acceleration at the top of the object and I would like to know what is the equivalent moment (or torque) at the the bottom.

The shape is not a "standard" one as per the book, but i was able to calculate the radius of gyration using *Creo*. I then used the following formulae:

*Moment of inertia*: 
$$
I = Radius^2 \times Mass
$$
Where:
 - *radius* is the radius of gyration in meter
 - *mass* is the mass of the moving object in kg
 - *I* the moment of inertia in $kg/m^2$

Then 
*Moment*:
$$
Moment = I \times a
$$
Where:
 - *I* is moment of inertia calculated previously
 - *a* is the linear acceleration measured in $g$

It gives me very small values, which I don't believe. Did I miss something in the methodology?

Thanks for the help!

[image: Attached is the experimental set up]

Comment: Your $a$ is the angular acceleration.

Comment: @Farcher do you mean that I need to convert the linear acceleration measured into rotational acceleration?

Comment: I think that is so.

Comment: @Farcher it looks like it was the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Farcher said in the comments, your mistake is that you interpreted the moment equation incorrectly (because of the confusing use of $a$).

In my experience it is usually written as $$M = I \times \alpha$$ where $\alpha$ is angular acceleration.

The conversion from linear acceleration to angular acceleration is pretty straightforward.  Using the formula $$a = \alpha \times r$$ we can find $$\alpha = \frac ar$$ where r is the straight line distance between the point of rotation and the place where you measure linear acceleration (as shown in this terrible MS paint drawing).
[image: Radius for angular acceleration]

You may have already figured this all out from Farchers comment (you did the rest of the problem yourself, this part is fairly easy), but I figure I'll put an answer here for reference.

Comment: Indeed, I corrected my calculation using @Farcher's comment (it follows your explanation), it makes a lot more sense when looking at the numbers!

Comment: @Ryderc I can imagine that using $\frac {rads}{s^2}$ would give some pretty nonsense results here.